# ifChecked doesn't send any callback to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I'm using the `ifChecked` event of the `iCheck` plugin as shown below:

```
$('#regular').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

I try to check if my `input` is checked, but is doesn't return any data, my input looks like

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="regular" class="icheck"  id="regular">
<label for="regular">Regular</label>
```

But it doesn't return any alert message.

Comment: Easier said than done `ifChecked` lol

Comment: @cookiemonster this is iCheck http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

Comment: I suspect there might be another element in the document with the same id `regular`.  Ids should be unique.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/uYtJ4/20/ click to the left of the text

Comment: @Anton I came to the same conclusion: http://jsfiddle.net/yZ2pP/ I think Michael forgot the initialize the plugin with `.iCheck()`.

Comment: Did you wrap your code in DOM ready handler? $(function(){/*code*/});

Comment: @kapa Ah yea, most likley

Comment: Yea, i wrap, and i have other function not iCheck, they work, i'm using CoreAdmin theme https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/core-admin-WB0135486

Comment: @Michael If you are not using `iCheck()`, there will be no `ifChecked` event - this is the plugin that provides it.

Comment: Ok, saw iCheck. 1) CHeck your bind it's in a ready function. 2) Be sure to customize your input with $('#regoular').iCheck();

Comment: CoreAdmins updated iCheck in verson 1.2 according to your link, so you are using iCheck.

Comment: @MrPk its initializes it with class = icheck, and when i initialize with `$('#regoular').iCheck();` it doesnt shows the radio button!

Comment: @Michael Check what iCheck theme you are using, because you must include this parameter when using .iCheck() `$('#regoular').iCheck({
        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-orange'
    });`

Comment: I think that you miss the css skin and so the plugin doesn't recognize your radio as an iCheck item. However the sample name the class as "iradio" not "icheck". <div class="iradio">
  <input type="radio" name="quux[2]" id="baz[2]">
</div>

Comment: Thank you all for fast answers, guess the old version of iCheck on my Core admin theme, was the main cause of problem, i updated it, and all works fine now, thanks! :)